# How to clear MemoryCache?

Tags: c#, caching, memory, .net-4.0, memorycache

I have created a cache using the MemoryCache class. I add some items to it but when I need to reload the cache I want to clear it first. What is the quickest way to do this? Should I loop through all the items and remove them one at a time or is there a better way?

Comment: For .NET core check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49425102/3170087) answer.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

[`Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.dispose.aspx) the existing MemoryCache and create a new MemoryCache object.

Comment: I initially used MemoryCache.Default, causing Dispose to give me some grief. Still, Dispose ended up being the best solution I could find. Thanks.

Comment: @LaustN can you elaborate on the "grief" caused by MemoryCache.Default? I'm currently using MemoryCache.Default... MSDN's MemoryCache documentation makes me wonder if disposing and recreating is recommended: "Do not create MemoryCache instances unless it is required. If you create cache instances in client and Web applications, the MemoryCache instances should be created early in the application life cycle." Does this apply to .Default? I'm not saying using Dispose is wrong, I'm honestly just looking for clarification on all this.

Comment: Thought it was worth mentioning that `Dispose` _does_ invoke any `CacheEntryRemovedCallback` attached to current cached items.

Comment: @ElonU: The following Stack Overflow answer explains some of the grief you may encounter disposing of the default instance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8043556/216440 .  To quote: "The state of the cache is set to indicate that the cache is disposed. Any attempt to call public caching methods that change the state of the cache, such as methods that add, remove, or retrieve cache entries, might cause unexpected behavior. For example, if you call the Set method after the cache is disposed, a no-op error occurs."

Answer (score 62):

## The problem with enumeration

The [MemoryCache.GetEnumerator() Remarks section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.getenumerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) warns: "Retrieving an enumerator for a MemoryCache instance is a resource-intensive and blocking operation. Therefore, the enumerator should not be used in production applications."

**Here's why**, explained in pseudocode of the GetEnumerator() implementation:

```
Create a new Dictionary object (let's call it AllCache)
For Each per-processor segment in the cache (one Dictionary object per processor)
{
    Lock the segment/Dictionary (using lock construct)
    Iterate through the segment/Dictionary and add each name/value pair one-by-one
       to the AllCache Dictionary (using references to the original MemoryCacheKey
       and MemoryCacheEntry objects)
}
Create and return an enumerator on the AllCache Dictionary
```

Since the implementation splits the cache across multiple Dictionary objects, it must bring everything together into a single collection in order to hand back an enumerator.  Every call to GetEnumerator executes the full copy process detailed above.  The newly created Dictionary contains references to the original internal key and value objects, so your actual cached data values are not duplicated.

**The warning in the documentation is correct.  Avoid GetEnumerator() -- including all of the answers above that use LINQ queries.**

## A better and more flexible solution

Here's an efficient way of clearing the cache that simply builds on the existing change monitoring infrastructure.  It also provides the flexibility to clear either the entire cache or just a named subset and has none of the problems discussed above.

```
// By Thomas F. Abraham (http://www.tfabraham.com)
namespace CacheTest
{
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Runtime.Caching;

    public class SignaledChangeEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public SignaledChangeEventArgs(string name = null) { this.Name = name; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Cache change monitor that allows an app to fire a change notification
    /// to all associated cache items.
    /// </summary>
    public class SignaledChangeMonitor : ChangeMonitor
    {
        // Shared across all SignaledChangeMonitors in the AppDomain
        private static event EventHandler<SignaledChangeEventArgs> Signaled;

        private string _name;
        private string _uniqueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        public override string UniqueId
        {
            get { return _uniqueId; }
        }

        public SignaledChangeMonitor(string name = null)
        {
            _name = name;
            // Register instance with the shared event
            SignaledChangeMonitor.Signaled += OnSignalRaised;
            base.InitializationComplete();
        }

        public static void Signal(string name = null)
        {
            if (Signaled != null)
            {
                // Raise shared event to notify all subscribers
                Signaled(null, new SignaledChangeEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            SignaledChangeMonitor.Signaled -= OnSignalRaised;
        }

        private void OnSignalRaised(object sender, SignaledChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Name) || string.Compare(e.Name, _name, true) == 0)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(
                    _uniqueId + " notifying cache of change.", "SignaledChangeMonitor");
                // Cache objects are obligated to remove entry upon change notification.
                base.OnChanged(null);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class CacheTester
    {
        public static void TestCache()
        {
            MemoryCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;

            // Add data to cache
            for (int idx = 0; idx < 50; idx++)
            {
                cache.Add("Key" + idx.ToString(), "Value" + idx.ToString(), GetPolicy(idx));
            }

            // Flush cached items associated with "NamedData" change monitors
            SignaledChangeMonitor.Signal("NamedData");

            // Flush all cached items
            SignaledChangeMonitor.Signal();
        }

        private static CacheItemPolicy GetPolicy(int idx)
        {
            string name = (idx % 2 == 0) ? null : "NamedData";

            CacheItemPolicy cip = new CacheItemPolicy();
            cip.AbsoluteExpiration = System.DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1);
            cip.ChangeMonitors.Add(new SignaledChangeMonitor(name));
            return cip;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like an implementation for the missing Region functionality.

Comment: Very nice. I've been trying to implement something using chained memorycache monitors and guids but it was starting to get a bit ugly as I tried to tighten up the functionality.

Comment: I would not recommend this pattern for general use. 1. Its slow, no fault of the implementation, but the dispose method is extremely slow. 2. If your evicting items from the cache with an expiration, Change monitor still gets called. 3. My machine was swallowing all of the CPU, and taking a really long time to clear 30k items from the cache when I was running performance tests. A few times after waiting 5+ minutes I just killed the tests.

Comment: @AaronM What was your solution after abandoning this one?

Comment: @PascalMathys Unfortunately, There isn't a better solution than this. I ended up using it, despite the disadvantages, as its still a better solution than using the enumeration.

Comment: @AaronM Is this solution still better than just disposing of the cache and instantiating a new one?

Comment: Here's an improved version of this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55414488/56621

Answer (score 38):

From http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/723620/memorycache-class-needs-a-clear-method

The workaround is:

```
List<string> cacheKeys = MemoryCache.Default.Select(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList();
foreach (string cacheKey in cacheKeys)
{
    MemoryCache.Default.Remove(cacheKey);
}
```

Comment: From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.getenumerator.aspx): _Retrieving an enumerator for a MemoryCache instance is a resource-intensive and blocking operation. Therefore, the enumerator should not be used in production applications._

Comment: I don't think this is the same as retrieving an enumerator. This is actually pretty fast and doesn't enumerate anything. Still... I like disposing the cache myself.

Comment: @emberdude It's exactly the same as retrieving an enumerator - what do you thing the implementation of `Select()` does?

Comment: Personally, I'm using this in my unit test [TestInitialize] function to clear out the memory cache for each unit test. Otherwise the cache persists across unit tests giving unintended results when trying to compare performance between 2 functions.

Comment: @JacobMorrison arguably, unit tests are not a "production application" :)

Comment: @Mels arguably, unit tests should be written to the same standards as "production application"! :)

Answer (score 25):

```
var cacheItems = cache.ToList();

foreach (KeyValuePair<String, Object> a in cacheItems)
{
    cache.Remove(a.Key);
}
```

Comment: This has the same risk as @Tony's response; please see my comment under that.

Comment: @TrueWill Who is or was @Tony?

Comment: @AlexAngas - He may have changed his name to magritte. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183270/how-to-clear-the-net-4-memorycache/22388943#22388943

Answer (score 13):

If performance isn't an issue then this nice one-liner will do the trick:

```
cache.ToList().ForEach(a => cache.Remove(a.Key));
```

Answer (score 10):

It seems that there is a [Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.trim(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

So to clear all contents you'd just do

```
cache.Trim(100)
```

*EDIT:*
after digging some more, it seems that looking into Trim is not worth your time

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/831755/memorycache-trim-method-doesnt-evict-100-of-the-items

[How do I clear a System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043381/how-do-i-clear-a-system-runtime-caching-memorycache)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, saved me from the pain of a pointless rabbit hole...

Answer (score 4):

Ran across this, and based on it, wrote a slightly more effective, parallel clear method:

```
    public void ClearAll()
    {
        var allKeys = _cache.Select(o => o.Key);
        Parallel.ForEach(allKeys, key => _cache.Remove(key));
    }
```

Comment: Did you test it to see if it's quicker (or slower) ?

Answer (score 3):

You could also do something like this:

```
Dim _Qry = (From n In CacheObject.AsParallel()
           Select n).ToList()
For Each i In _Qry
    CacheObject.Remove(i.Key)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You can dispose the MemoryCache.Default cache and then re-set the private field singleton to null, to make it recreate the MemoryCache.Default.

```
       var field = typeof(MemoryCache).GetField("s_defaultCache",
            BindingFlags.Static |
            BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        field.SetValue(null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was only interested in clearing the cache and found this as an option, when using the c# GlobalCachingProvider

```
                var cache = GlobalCachingProvider.Instance.GetAllItems();
                if (dbOperation.SuccessLoadingAllCacheToDB(cache))
                {
                    cache.Clear();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

a bit improved version of magritte answer.

```
var cacheKeys = MemoryCache.Default.Where(kvp.Value is MyType).Select(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList();
foreach (string cacheKey in cacheKeys)
{
    MemoryCache.Default.Remove(cacheKey);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This discussion is also being done here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/answers/983399/view.html

I wrote an answer there and I'll transcribe it here:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using ServiceStack;

public static class IMemoryCacheExtensions
{
    static readonly List<object> entries = new();

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes all entries, added via the "TryGetValueExtension()" method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cache"></param>
    public static void Clear(this IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < entries.Count; i++)
        {
            cache.Remove(entries[i]);
        }
        entries.Clear();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use this extension method, to be able to remove all your entries later using "Clear()" method
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TItem"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="cache"></param>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool TryGetValueExtension<TItem>(this IMemoryCache cache, object key, out TItem value)
    {
        entries.AddIfNotExists(key);

        if (cache.TryGetValue(key, out object result))
        {
            if (result == null)
            {
                value = default;
                return true;
            }

            if (result is TItem item)
            {
                value = item;
                return true;
            }
        }

        value = default;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use IMomeryCache that add with DI container in my controller and I use this code for clear cache:

```
  private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;
    public AdminController(IMemoryCache memoryCache) 
    { 
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }

    [HttpGet("ClearCache")]
    public IActionResult ClearCache()
    {
        ClearMemoryCache();

        return Ok();
    }

    private  void ClearMemoryCache()
    {
        var cacheImplType = typeof(MemoryCache);
        var entriesField = cacheImplType.GetField("_entries", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var entries = (IDictionary)entriesField?.GetValue(_memoryCache);
        entries?.Clear();
    }
```

its worked for me.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your input. I was also looking for this topic. But none of the answers worked for me. 

Key differences:

    Utilizing Reflection: My solution leverages Reflection to access cache keys with a DI container, unlike existing answers.

    DI Container Scenarios: Tailored for cases involving DI containers, providing a practical alternative.

    Specific Use Case: Designed for a specific use case with a DI container and restricted cache key access.

Hope this helps. Open to discussion and improvements.

Comment: That does help. Can you [edit] you answer to include this?