# C# find a WebCache with partial key string?

Tags: c#, regex

```
using System.Web.Helpers
```

Let's say I added those..

```
WebCache.Set("apple_1","some value")
WebCache.Set("apple_2","some value")
WebCache.Set("apple_3","some value")
WebCache.Set("peach_1","some value")
WebCache.Set("peach_2","some value")
WebCache.Set("peach_3","some value")
```

Is there a way that I find all the Caches the key starts with "apple" and remove them? maybe Regex.. maybe not, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if `System.Web.Helpers.WebCache` is simply a wrapper round the "default" MemoryCache instance, which you can access via `MemoryCache.Default`.

You can then enumerate over the entries, check if the keys match your criteria and call `MemoryCache.Remove()` to remove those that you don't want.

*However*: this has its caveats and I would suggest to think at least twice before going down this road:

1. Depending on the concurrent insertions into the cache, you might never end up with all entries being removed that you like. Because while you are at it, new entries - which you would normally want to removed - might already be inserted by someone else.
2. Enumerating a MemoryCache is being warned as "resource intensive" and should be avoid. Double so on the "Default" cache instance which potentially is being used by quite some facilities as their backing cache (Details see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22388943/21567)). Actually [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.getenumerator.aspx) goes so far as telling you "don't do it in production applications"

It would probably be best to keep track of the entries you added elsewhere, and than use that "index" to remove the entries explicitly if you really need to. Just make sure that this "elsewhere" doesn't end up as being a memory leak, that is you must make sure that it is cleared eventually (you could maybe use MemoryCache's change notifications for that).