# ASP.NET Core clear cache from IMemoryCache (set by Set method of CacheExtensions class)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

*On first look this looks duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48658912/clear-asp-net-core-2-0-imemorycache), but I am not asking how to clear cache for EF.*

How can I clear entire cache set by `IMemoryCache` interface?

```
    public CacheService(IMemoryCache memoryCache) 
    {
        this._memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }

    public async Task<List<string>> GetCacheItem()
    {
        if (!this._memoryCache.TryGetValue("Something", out List<string> list))
        {
            list= await this ...

            this._memoryCache.Set("Something", list, new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetPriority(CacheItemPriority.NeverRemove));
        }

        return list;
    }
```

This is just an example. I have many classes/methods that are storing values to cache. Now I need to remove them all.

My keys are, in some cases, created dynamically, so I don't know which keys I need to remove. Clear would be perfect.

I could write my own interface and class which would internally use `IMemoryCache`, but this seems overkill. Is there any easier options?

Comment: You could downcast to MemoryCache and call Clear().

Comment: Do as @Tratcher suggested and add an extension method targeting the `IMemoryCache` interface.

Comment: There is no clear function or extension method on MemoryCache that allows you to clear the cache. So casing to the implementation won't help either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I couldn't find any good solutions so, I wrote my own.
*In SamiAl90 solution (answer) I missed all properties from [ICacheEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.icacheentry?view=aspnetcore-2.0) interface.*

Internally it uses [IMemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.IMemoryCache?view=aspnetcore-2.0).
Use case is exactly the same with 2 additional features:

1. Clear all items from the memory cache
2. Iterate through all key/value pairs

You have to register a singleton:

```cs
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IMyCache, MyMemoryCache>();
```

Use case:

```cs
public MyController(IMyCache cache)
{
    this._cache = cache;
}

[HttpPut]
public IActionResult ClearCache()
{
    this._cache.Clear();
    return new JsonResult(true);
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult ListCache()
{
    var result = this._cache.Select(t => new
    {
        Key = t.Key,
        Value = t.Value
    }).ToArray();
    return new JsonResult(result);
}
```

Source:

```cs
public interface IMyCache : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<object, object>>, IMemoryCache
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Clears all cache entries.
    /// </summary>
    void Clear();
}

public class MyMemoryCache : IMyCache
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<object, ICacheEntry> _cacheEntries = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, ICacheEntry>();

    public MyMemoryCache(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        this._memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this._memoryCache.Dispose();
    }

    private void PostEvictionCallback(object key, object value, EvictionReason reason, object state)
    {
        if (reason != EvictionReason.Replaced)
            this._cacheEntries.TryRemove(key, out var _);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc cref="IMemoryCache.TryGetValue"/>
    public bool TryGetValue(object key, out object value)
    {
        return this._memoryCache.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create or overwrite an entry in the cache and add key to Dictionary.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">An object identifying the entry.</param>
    /// <returns>The newly created <see cref="T:Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.ICacheEntry" /> instance.</returns>
    public ICacheEntry CreateEntry(object key)
    {
        var entry = this._memoryCache.CreateEntry(key);
        entry.RegisterPostEvictionCallback(this.PostEvictionCallback);
        this._cacheEntries.AddOrUpdate(key, entry, (o, cacheEntry) =>
        {
            cacheEntry.Value = entry;
            return cacheEntry;
        });
        return entry;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc cref="IMemoryCache.Remove"/>
    public void Remove(object key)
    {
        this._memoryCache.Remove(key);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc cref="IMyCache.Clear"/>
    public void Clear()
    {
        foreach (var cacheEntry in this._cacheEntries.Keys.ToList())
            this._memoryCache.Remove(cacheEntry);
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<object, object>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this._cacheEntries.Select(pair => new KeyValuePair<object, object>(pair.Key, pair.Value.Value)).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets keys of all items in MemoryCache.
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerator<object> Keys => this._cacheEntries.Keys.GetEnumerator();
}

public static class MyMemoryCacheExtensions
{
    public static T Set<T>(this IMyCache cache, object key, T value)
    {
        var entry = cache.CreateEntry(key);
        entry.Value = value;
        entry.Dispose();

        return value;
    }

    public static T Set<T>(this IMyCache cache, object key, T value, CacheItemPriority priority)
    {
        var entry = cache.CreateEntry(key);
        entry.Priority = priority;
        entry.Value = value;
        entry.Dispose();

        return value;
    }

    public static T Set<T>(this IMyCache cache, object key, T value, DateTimeOffset absoluteExpiration)
    {
        var entry = cache.CreateEntry(key);
        entry.AbsoluteExpiration = absoluteExpiration;
        entry.Value = value;
        entry.Dispose();

        return value;
    }

    public static T Set<T>(this IMyCache cache, object key, T value, TimeSpan absoluteExpirationRelativeToNow)
    {
        var entry = cache.CreateEntry(key);
        entry.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = absoluteExpirationRelativeToNow;
        entry.Value = value;
        entry.Dispose();

        return value;
    }

    public static T Set<T>(this IMyCache cache, object key, T value, MemoryCacheEntryOptions options)
    {
        using (var entry = cache.CreateEntry(key))
        {
            if (options != null)
                entry.SetOptions(options);

            entry.Value = value;
        }

        return value;
    }

    public static TItem GetOrCreate<TItem>(this IMyCache cache, object key, Func<ICacheEntry, TItem> factory)
    {
        if (!cache.TryGetValue(key, out var result))
        {
            var entry = cache.CreateEntry(key);
            result = factory(entry);
            entry.SetValue(result);
            entry.Dispose();
        }

        return (TItem)result;
    }

    public static async Task<TItem> GetOrCreateAsync<TItem>(this IMyCache cache, object key, Func<ICacheEntry, Task<TItem>> factory)
    {
        if (!cache.TryGetValue(key, out object result))
        {
            var entry = cache.CreateEntry(key);
            result = await factory(entry);
            entry.SetValue(result);
            entry.Dispose();
        }

        return (TItem)result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey can you use this to clear the cache items created with <cache> tag helper? If so, how? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what is `<cache>` tag helper.

Answer (score 14):

If you cast `IMemoryCache` to just `MemoryCache` you should now have a `Compact` method which you can call with a parameter value of `1.0`, causing the cache to clear.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.memorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

If you feel that is too hacky or your `IMemoryCache` is something else, read on...

Disposing and removing key by key is not a good idea, too many failure points. I have used this code in production and unit tests, it works well. I have yet to find a good answer as to why `IMemoryCache` is missing a `Clear` method.

```
PropertyInfo prop = cache.GetType().GetProperty("EntriesCollection", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
object innerCache = prop.GetValue(cache);
MethodInfo clearMethod = innerCache.GetType().GetMethod("Clear", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
clearMethod.Invoke(innerCache, null);
```

Comment: answer worked for me. I called _cache.Compact(1) and it reset the cache

Comment: Worked for me to clear CacheTagHelper cache from CacheTagHelperMemoryCacheFactory.cache

Comment: I want to add that `Compact(1)` will not remove items added with option `CacheItemPriority.NeverRemove`

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. I looked up the code on github because my initial idea was to simply dispose it, even when it would be dirty. Caching-Middleware registers a single implementation of [IMemoryCache](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/MemoryCache.cs) as singleton.

When you called dispose on it once, you [can not access the cache functions](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/28a386c8b69caa84cb1e66802e4ba94d31f38f45/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/MemoryCache.cs#L471) ever again, until you restart the whole service.

So a workaround to accomplish this would be to store all keys that have been added in singleton service that you implement yourself. For instance smth like

```
public class MemoryCacheKeyStore : IMemoryCacheKeyStore, IDisposeable
{
   private readonly List<object> Keys = new List<object>();

   public void AddKey(object key) ...

   public object[] GetKeys() ....

   public void Dispose()
   {
      this.Keys.Clear();
      GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
   }
}
```

With that you could at somepoint access all keys, iterate through them and call the [Remove(object key)](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/28a386c8b69caa84cb1e66802e4ba94d31f38f45/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/MemoryCache.cs#L249) function on the cache.

Dirty workaround, might cause some trouble but as far as I can tell this is the only way to remove all items at once without a service reboot :)

Answer (score 1):

This discussion is also being done here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/answers/983399/view.html

I wrote an answer there and I'll transcribe it here:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using ServiceStack;

public static class IMemoryCacheExtensions
{
    static readonly List<object> entries = new();

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes all entries, added via the "TryGetValueExtension()" method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cache"></param>
    public static void Clear(this IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < entries.Count; i++)
        {
            cache.Remove(entries[i]);
        }
        entries.Clear();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use this extension method, to be able to remove all your entries later using "Clear()" method
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TItem"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="cache"></param>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool TryGetValueExtension<TItem>(this IMemoryCache cache, object key, out TItem value)
    {
        entries.AddIfNotExists(key);

        if (cache.TryGetValue(key, out object result))
        {
            if (result == null)
            {
                value = default;
                return true;
            }

            if (result is TItem item)
            {
                value = item;
                return true;
            }
        }

        value = default;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When using IMemoryTask it is a good idea to keep all your keys in constants to avoid the use of magic strings. Then create a string array that contains all your keys.

Clearing the cache then becomes very simple and you can do it like this:

```
private void ClearCache()
{
  foreach (var key in MemoryCacheConstants.AllKeys)
  {
    _memoryCache.Remove(key);
  }
}
```

Comment: The author states that some keys are dynamic so a list of keys known at build-time (that may or may not have actual cache entries) doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -2):

In ASP.NET Core, you can add `services.AddMemoryCache()` in `ConfigureServices` of `Startup`. Once in controller, just use DI of `IMemoryCache` parameter like this:

```
NameController(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
```

Then, when you want remove or clear cache use

```
memoryCache.Remove(yourkeycache)
```

This works from 1.1

Comment: This does not solve the problem of the author: `My keys are, in some cases, created dynamically, so I don't know which keys I need to remove.`