# Remove cache created with <cache> tag helper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, caching

I have used `<cache>` tag helper in my Asp.Net Core 3.1 website to cache some parts of the page. However, in some situations I want to clear these cache entries and make the website re-create those. How can I achieve that? I tried the code mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49425102/603200) but couldn't get it to work. When I register the service the application seems to ignore it and no entries get cached in my custom service.

Comment: What do you mean by " clear these cache entries and make the website re-create those" ?Do the [Cache Tag Helper Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/cache-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1) help you complete what you want ?

Comment: @XueliChen no the attributes are for when I know beforehand  when I want the cache to expire. Usually I don't want these cached sections to expire for at least several days but sometimes I make a change in the data and want to invalidate the cache and ask the website to render that section again.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori, do you get any solution for that. I assume it is possible to get the collection by reflection

Comment: @sina_Islam Unfortunately no. Please let me know if you find anything.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori, I get a workaround for the above scenario. You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70272433/get-value-of-vary-by-attribute-of-cache-tag-helper-from-c-sharp/70446789#70446789

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it:

```
    private readonly CacheTagHelperMemoryCacheFactory factory;

    public MyClass(CacheTagHelperMemoryCacheFactory factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }
```

and later

```
    (this.factory.Cache as MemoryCache).Compact(1.0);
```

Comment: What is this class? Is it a tag helper? If so, how can I access the code on the bottom? Make it a function? How would I get the current cache helper?

Comment: This may be any class created using asp.net core dependency injection system. For example it may be a model class.
The idea is that you accept CacheTagHelperMemoryCacheFactory in constructor and use it later anywhere in the class.

Comment: But if that's the case, how can I use it in razor like I mentioned in my question. I'm looking for a way to use a tag handler on razor and invalidate it if necessary.

Comment: If your tag helper is used inside <cache> tag, your tag helper is called only when cache is empty. Once content was generated it's stored in the cache. Next time page is rendered your tag does not get called. The content is taken from the cache as string. One way to make your tag helper to re-render is to clear the cache. I'm showing how to do it above. But you can't do it inside of your tag helper logic if it is called inside of the <cache> region because once cached your tag helper will not get called. Ideally you should drop cache where the data gets changed.

Comment: Ah, this solved my problem of trying to clear all the pages cached with CacheTagHelper.